# Ordering of rows chronological by one field, then chronological by another field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

If we have a table that logs when users sign in,

```
---------------------------------
| user    |  time               |
---------------------------------
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:04:36 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:06:43 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:09:13 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:12:23 |
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:13:41 |
---------------------------------
```

and we want to order the rows by which user logged in first, and then every subsequent login by that user ordered by time,

```
---------------------------------
| user    |  time               |
---------------------------------
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:04:36 |
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:13:41 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:06:43 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:09:13 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:12:23 |
---------------------------------
```

how could we write the `ORDER BY` clause to do that?

If we use `ORDER BY name, time` then we get `Jack` before `Jill` based on alphabetic sort of name.

```
---------------------------------
| user    |  time               |
---------------------------------
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:06:43 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:09:13 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:12:23 |
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:04:36 |
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:13:41 |
---------------------------------
```

If we use `ORDER BY time, name` then we just get the names mixed in whatever order they signed in.

```
---------------------------------
| user    |  time               |
---------------------------------
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:04:36 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:06:43 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:09:13 |
| Jack    | 2014-09-13 21:12:23 |
| Jill    | 2014-09-13 21:13:41 |
---------------------------------
```

We could use `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table` to get only the names in chronological order, and then somehow get the rest of the rows... but how to do it in one query? Is there a way to do a subquery in an `ORDER BY` clause? `ORDER BY (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table)` doesn't work.

I feel like this should be simple, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're assuming that users cannot login at the same time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join with a subquery which gets the minimum log in time for a user, and just order by that time. The ordering by a.user is required in case two users have the same first login time so that the results won't be intermixed.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
JOIN ( SELECT user, MIN(time) min_time FROM table1 GROUP BY user) b
  ON a.user=b.user
ORDER BY b.min_time, a.user, a.time
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eec2d/4).

Comment: Sigh, I knew it would be simple. How could I forget MIN(). Thanks so much!